# Mix pbr materials in texture paint mode

Tags: texture-painting, pbr

[image]I have two textures, each with an albedo and a roughness.
Let's name them A and B.
i have a source image texture_A_albedo.jpg texture_A_roughness.jpg, texture_B_albedo.jpg, texture_B_roughness.jpg

I'd like to be able to use them in texture paint mode to blend them on an object (stencil mode) and take advantage of all the brush blending modes. Paint where I want texture A and where I want texture B and have it do the same operation on the roughness (with same brush strokes)so that at the end I get a texture_Object_albedo and a texture_Object_roughness.

I haven't found a tutorial on how to do this. Is this possible?
i hope my question is clear enough :)

Comment: So you want to repeat the same brush strokes on two separate textures by applying different brush textures as stencils in the process? Please provide some examples of what you want to achieve in the form of screenshots or diagrams. This will increase the chance of getting a correct answer,.

Comment: @RumenBelev Yes, I'd like to reproduce what I did with the albedo on a roughness texture so that where I put the albedo_A I can have the roughness_A and so where I put the Albedo_B I can have the roughness_B associated. It's not just a question of mask, as I'm in stencil mode mapping, I can scale, translate, rotate, etc...

Comment: Have you considered a stencil image between the two shaders as a mix shader input and starting with texture A as all visible and then paint the stencil to reveal texture B?  This seems to be the only way to do this unless you are painting on an RGB image and using the separate RGB node as a split for stencil.